# Read formatted input with cin?

Tags: c++

Let's imagine this input : 01202014 (ddmmyyyy) .

My question is :

How can I read the input to three separated variables using pure C++ ?

As far as I know this would work , but this would be a mix C/C++ and I'm wondering if there is any solution that is pure C++.

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()

 {


 int mm, dd, yy;

 scanf_s("%2d%2d%4d", &mm, &dd, &yy);
 //How can I do the same with Cin? std::cin 
 std::cout << mm << "/" << dd << "/" << yy;


 system("pause");

 }
```

Example :

Input : `01232009`

Objective :

```
mm = 1;
dd = 23;
yy  = 2009
```

Comment: You can use option like -dd in c++

Comment: Why not just: `char c; cin >> mm >> c >> dd >> c >> yy;`

Comment: @ooga What I want to do is a single input. For example , if the user enters "01292009" then format it to separate variables. Your solution would prompt the user for an input 5 times.

Comment: How would it "prompt the user" 5 times??? Try it.

Comment: @ooga I edit the question. You were right , but my problem is if the input is like this MMDDYYYY

Comment: If the input format is certain. why don't slice the string? such as `string day(date, 0, 2);` then convert to `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need in *DDMMYYYY* format, you can have following :

```
std::string date ;
std::getline( std::cin, date );

int dd,mm,yy;
if ( date.size() ==  8 ) // Other checkings left for you
{   
    mm = std::stoi( date.substr(0,2) );   
    dd = std::stoi( date.substr(2,2) ); 
    yy = std::stoi( date.substr(4) ); 

    std::cout << dd << "/" << mm << "/" << yy ;
}
```

See [Here](http://rextester.com/YJH39492)

<sup>And now please [don't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580816/read-formatted-input-with-cin/26581001#comment41778474_26580816) question !</sup>